Next.js 14.2.5 - Previous Group Data Persisting Across Route Group Transitions
I am using Next.js 14.2.5 and have set up route groups as follows:
app
├── (group1)
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   ├── page1
│   │   └── page.tsx
├── (group2)
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   ├── page2
│   │   └── page.tsx


When navigating between page1 and page2, the previous group's layout.css is not removed. This happens when using  to transition from page1 to page2. The  still contains the layout.css from group1, causing mixed styles.
I expected the previous group's data, including layout.css, to be cleared when transitioning across route groups. However, the styles from group1 remain in the  after navigating to page2.
I tried:

Replacing  with , which clears the styles but does a full page reload.
Performing a full page reload, which works but is not ideal for maintaining the SPA experience.

Additionally, similar issues occur when submitting a POST form that redirects across groups. I want a way to clear the previous group's styles and ensure only the new group's styles are applied.
